# OAuth authentication or JWT authentication using TIBCO for GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-oauth, tibco, tibco-business-works

I want to invoke GCP REST API from TIBCO BW6.X but before that i need to authenticate my request either using OAuth or JWT. In BW5.X there was option to configure OAuth authentication in 'Invoke REST API' pallette but in BW6 there is no option to configure it and we have to do OAuth authentication separately using http activities. I have created OAuth client in my  GCP account and have client_id, client_secret and other details with me. But not sure how can i get access token using  TIBCO BW 6.X.
If anyone has any idea about same, please share.